# Run function on components when service value updated (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, service

I'm creating an app with a structure like this:

[image: structure]

When you click an item in MenuComponent, it emits an object to the dashboard-component, which is then sent from there to the OverViewComponent and the UserComponent. They in turn run a function in the @Input() to fetch various data based on the data they receive, which in turn can be manipulated.

However, I need to be able to save changed data together from the outer wrapper, and since I didn't want to emit data back out to the DashboardComponent I opted to use a service with shared variables. This works fine, except I have not found a similar way to @Input() to run functions on the components when the service variable changes. I need this to fetch fresh data when a new item is selected in the menu. I read some earlier posts here on SO, but most of those used BehaviorSubject to subscribe to changes - but I couldn't find any posts where they ran a function on the component when the variable changed in the service. The variable is a JSON-object, by the way. Any pointers is appreciated!

EDIT: Before I added the service, I emitted the value using @Output from MenuComponent to DashboardComponent. I received it through the selector in DashboardComponent with @Input:

```
<app-menu-component (emitGroup)="getGroup($event)"></app-menu-component>
```

I then used @Output again to emit it onwards to UserComponent through the selector.

```
<app-user [group]="selectedGroup"></app-user>
```

Then, in UserComponent, I could run a function in the @Input when the data changed, like this:

```
  @Input()
  set group(g) {
    this.selectedGroup = g;
    this.findUsers(this.selectedGroup); // this is what I want to achieve
  }
```

Is there any way to do something similar from the service?

Comment: You probably want something like this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. If not, then post a minimal complete example (code !!) reproducing the issue.

Comment: I can't really share the code, unfortunately. I added some additional info to the main post to better explain what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Well you emit the changed value from a Subject in the service, and you subscribe to this subject in the component, doing whatever you want in the subscribe callback function. Have you read the example I linked to?

Comment: Yes, but I did not understand that you could do whatever inside the subscribe. If that is the case, and that this will run every time I do .next from the service, then I guess that could probably work how I want. :)

Comment: you can use ``BehaviorialSubject`` or just a ``Subject`` to do this work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question and its description , i think you want something like this :

You can create a service such as this :

`shared.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

mySubject : Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
myData : any ;

myDataSetter(data : any){
 this.myData = data;
 this.mySubject.next(this.myData);
}
```

}

Use `myDataSetter` from your `menucomponent` to set the data that is changed .

```
in your component subscribe to the subject in the service during the ``ngOnInit()`` this way : 

this._sharedService.mySubject.subscribe((data) => {
 //call my function
})
```

Comment: I already had the service - but this was exactly how I did it after the clarification from Jb Nizet yesterday. Marking answer as accepted. :)